# How to pass arguments to strings in eval() javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, string, eval

Let we have the user input stored in a variable t,

`let t = '[1,2,3,4].map(e=>"<div>{{ e }}</div>")';`.

Whereby a user is forced to write this syntax to execute,
so on

`t = t.replace(/\{\{(.*)?\}\}/g,"$1");`.

We will be getting new t as,

`t = '[1,2,3,4].map(e=>"<div> e </div>")'`.

So now the question arises is how to pass this string to `eval` so that it considers it as an argument variable not the String. So, the output becomes,

`<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>`.

Comment: t = '[1,2,3,4].map(e=>"<div>" +e +" </div>")'. otherwise it is considerd as a string  "+e +"

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `eval()` for anything. You're opening yourself up to security risks. See the MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!

Answer (score 1):

The answer would not be the same depending on the user input. In the current case, this code would work.

```js
t = '[1,2,3,4].map(e=>`<div> ${e} </div>`)'
```

you can get this string from the original as follows.

```js
t = t.replace(/"/g, '`').replace(/\{\{(.*)?\}\}/g, "${$1}")
```

Comment: If I use template literals, and pass the variables to it. Then what about the Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```js
let t = '[1,2,3,4].map(e=>"<div>{{"+e+"}}</div>")';

t = t.replace(/\{\{(.*)?\}\}/g,"$1");

t = eval(t);

t.forEach(v => {document.write(v)});
```

Comment: It's a user input, they are not supposed to put plus sign in the string.